# Batch script not going to correct label

Tags: batch-file

I was working on a batch script to unlock some accounts if they exist and go to a label depending on the outcome.

The current script works, kinda. It's just not going to the correct label at the end. I understand that the labels have to be in the correct order, but I just don't understand what this order is and how I would check for the errorlevels correctly.

```
@echo off

cls
echo -------------------
echo Unlocking Account0...
echo -------------------
pause
net user Account0 /active:yes
goto %ERRORLEVEL%

:0
cls
echo -------------------
echo Account0 unlocked successfully!
echo Press any key to reboot now. 
echo -------------------
pause
goto reboot


:2
cls
echo -------------------
echo Account0 not found. Unlocking Account1...
echo -------------------
pause
net user Account1 /active:yes
if errorlevel 2 goto 3
if errorlevel 0 goto 0


:3
cls
echo -------------------
echo Account0 and Account1 not found!
echo Please make sure that one of these accounts exist.
echo You can use the command "net user <accounthere> /active:yes" to manually unlock an account.
echo -------------------
pause
goto END

:END
cls
echo NONE FOUND, EXIT SCRIPT.

:reboot
cls
echo ACCOUNT FOUND, REBOOT HERE
```

That's it. Nothing fancy. It just doesn't go to the correct labels.

Comment: All fixed. I forgot about the eof label. Just adding goto:eof under the reboot label works fine, and there is no need for an END label.

Answer (score 0):

See IF /?

```
if errorlevel 2 goto 3
```

Will goto 3 if errorlevel is greater than or equal to 2
You may want:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto 3
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto 0
```

Comment: The problem is that if neither accounts are found, instead of goto END, it does goto reboot. Switching :END and :reboot around makes no difference.

Comment: Removed the echo off and cls to see what's going on. Basically, it does goto :END but then goes to :reboot as well. I just want it to abort the script when it goes to either :reboot or :end labels.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
goto END
```

use the built in

```
goto :EOF
```

which goes to the end of the file by default (note the colon).